# Divide and Conquer Find Missing Element in Second Array?

Tags: python

I have a textbook question that I am confused about. The problem gives a sorted list of size n and another unsorted list of size n - 1 with the same elements except with one element missing. The question states to make a divide and conquer algorithm that can find the missing element in linear time.

I know non divide and conquer algorithms such as the XOR method that can solve this in linear time, but I can't think of a divide and conquer technique. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What if you divide it into first and rest?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: They didn't specify how you divide it. You can have a division with only 1 item, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can. How would that help me though?

Comment: It is a divide and conquer technique that will allow you to effectively use one of the other methods you know.